# Dart checkbox, force check

Tags: html, methods, checkbox, dart

I'd like to ask if there is any method for forcing CheckBox to check. I've tried to use `Click();`, but without success. I was searching for something like `.setChecked(true);` but again no success. Is it because I'm using checkbox as InputElement?

```
void main() {
    InputElement ac = querySelector('#ac');  //Checkbox id="ac"
    Storage localStorage = window.localStorage; 
    String sAc = localStorage['ac'];
    if (sAc == '1') {
        ac.Click();
    }

    ac.onClick.listen((Event e){
        String status;
        if (ac.checked){
            status = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            status = '0';
        }
        localStorage['ac'] = status;
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
var cb = (document.querySelector('#ac') as CheckboxInputElement);
cb.checked = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now! I had one more problem that caused not working for click() and it was missing script linked to dart. I was 100% sure i was inserting it into html, but probably i missed it. Anyway Thanks!